# jQuery Templates - Replace DIV content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, templates

So I'm using jQuery templates and have the following code working in my application:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("StateList",
                            Model.States,
                            "< Select >"
                            )

        <div id="designCenters"></div>

        <script id="designCenterTemplate" type="text/html">
            <p><li>${Name}</li></p>
        </script>           
    }

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $("#StateList").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("/api/designcentersbystate/" + $(this).val(), 
              function (data) { 
                  $("#designCenterTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#designCenters")
               });
        });
    </script>
```

Since I'm calling .appendTo in the callback function parameter of the template function, obviously the list of design centers is added to the list. My goal is to REPLACE the content within `<div id="designCenters">` with the templated results.

Looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the success function like so:

```
function (data) { 
    $("#designCenters").html($("#designCenterTemplate").tmpl(data))
}
```

Or you could empty the container each time.

```
$("#designCenters").empty();
$("#designCenterTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#designCenters");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the html in an element like this:

```
$("#designCenters").html(YOUR HTML HERE);
```

Comment: I tried changing the template code to: $("#designCenterTemplate").tmpl(data).html("#designCenters") but that has no effect other than to cause it to completely stop showing the templated data (with no JS errors). Kinda new to jQuery so it's probably a basic issue with the way I'm calling it.

Comment: you were just using the html method incorrectly. My version is correct. Josiash's answer is similar to mine but more complete for your scenario